# Apache IP-based VirtualHost: Can't access .localhost TLD by ServerName, can access by IP

Tags: apache-2.4

Good morning.

Trying to get this to work but I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

My virtual host config file:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.11:80>
    ServerName test.localhost
    #...
</VirtualHost>
```

My /etc/hosts file:

```
...
127.0.0.11 test.localhost
...
```

When I go to http://127.0.0.11 it works, but when I go to http://test.localhost it doesn't--it falls back to a default site I've configured at `<VirtualHost _default_:*>...</VirtualHost>`.  I've been searching on this for a few hours now and am kind of at a loss, hope someone can give me a pointer on what to look at.

Thanks.

Comment: When you try to ping your domain name what IP is returned ?

Comment: @Froggiz It returns the intended IP, i.e. ping test.localhost goes to 127.0.0.11.  But I just realized my problem and will put an answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like all domains with the TLD of .localhost map to 127.0.0.1.  When I changed my virtual host ServerName to "test.local" and updated my /etc/hosts accordingly, it all worked fine.

From RFC2606:

> The ".localhost" TLD has traditionally been statically defined in host
> DNS implementations as having an A record pointing to the loop back IP
> address and is reserved for such use.  Any other use would conflict
> with widely deployed code which assumes this use.

I assume "the loop back IP address" is 127.0.0.1.

While I was able to ping and curl from http://test.localhost/ and get the right data, actually loading that URL from my web browser (chromium) was pulling from 127.0.0.1 as I observed in the request header for the default page in the network developer tool.  I guess chromium doesn't check if there's an /etc/hosts entry for anything request to a host with the .localhost TLD... I could go to http://onfasofn3noidsnfd90.localhost and it still mapped to my default website hosted on 127.0.0.1.

Refs:

- On the ".localhost" TLD - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.localhost
- The RFC describing the .localhost TLD - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606 - section 2 last paragraph
- A discussion thread on why chromium automatically resolves all host names matching *.localhost without checking the local host file (/etc/hosts or LMHOSTS).  *TL;DR: chromium working as intended* - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973

Comment: Also, as far as chromium's treatment of the .localhost TLD: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=489973  TL;DR: "working as intended".